# Obtaining the Lagrangian dual by relaxation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

A soft question:

Given the optimization problem:

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            & \text{minimize}
            & & x_2\\
            & \text{s.t.}
            & & 18x_1 + 11x_2 \geq 33\\
            &&& 10x_1 -18x_2 \leq 9\\
            &&& x_1,x_2 \in\{0,1,2,3\}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}

By relaxing the first constraint, we obtain the Lagrangian dual as follows:

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
        & \text{minimize}
        & & x_2\\
        & \text{s.t.}
        & & 18x_1 + 11x_2 \geq 33\\
        &&& conv(10x_1 -18x_2 \leq 9, \hspace{2mm}
        x_1,x_2 \in\{0,1,2,3\})
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}

$\iff$

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        & \text{minimize}
        & & x_2\\
        & \text{s.t.}
        & & 18x_1 + 11x_2 \geq 33\\
        &&& x_1 - 2x_2 \leq 0\\
        &&& x_1 -x_2 \leq 1 \\
        &&& x_1\leq3\\
        &&& x_2 \leq3
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

So my question is, how did the author derive the Lagrangian dual above? I was told to use the equation $w_{LD}=max\{cx:Dx\leq d,x\in conv(X)\}$, but am unsure how the last LP was obtained.

Comment: Just to clear up my doubt here, are you sure that you have the objective function of the dual written correctly? Since the primal has a minimization objective, the dual should have a maximization one.

Comment: @learning To me, it looks wrong as well, but its the answer provided not by me, so I posted this here to seek some clarification.